# What happened to Accessible[XYZ] in Zio 2?

Tags: scala, zio

What happened to Accessible[XYZ] in Zio 2?

Used and mentioned by Kit here: https://youtu.be/yXcqjQ7Kcwk?t=681

What are the recommended new patterns?

Answer (score 1):

Replaced by Service pattern from ZIO 2:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ScqDZp9X3c